# mySQL group by day, and take the last value each day to aggregate

Tags: mysql, aggregation

I know that this subject was already talked about some time, and I've got a working but really slow solution. I'm searching for a way of doing it faster.

I've got a table with datetime and temperature values. There is about one row per hour. Now I want to select the temperatures per day, but I want to have the last temperature each day.

So I tried this:

```
SELECT
DATE(t1.datetime), t1.temp
FROM
data t1
LEFT JOIN
data t2 ON (
    DATE(t2.datetime) = DATE(t1.datetime)
AND
    t2.datetime > t1.datetime
)
WHERE
t1.datetime >= ('2018-01-01' - INTERVAL 0 DAY)
AND
t1.datetime <= ('2018-02-22' + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
AND
t2.datumzeit IS NULL
ORDER BY
t1.datetime
```

This is realy slow, so I'm wondering if there is a faster solution?

Thank you very much!

BR

Comment: Please see [mcve]. You should be able to `GROUP BY DATE(datetime)` and get the `MAX(TIME(datetime))` and use that for your query but cannot be sure without [mcve].